# How do I store a golang template macro in vim

Tags: macos, go, vim, terminal, vim-macros

I want to store the following code permanently in the .vimrc file. Can anyone provide me the code to do so?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by "store the code permanently in .vimrc"? If you want the above code to be a template for any `go` file then I would suggest to put it in some directory inside `~/.vim/` and use `:read` command to read that template every time you open a `go` file.

Comment: add a snippet for the code in .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) does this automatically and provides other useful features for go development like running `gofmt` on save and adding commands for `go imports`